# Setting element "m" in array variable equal to value from active row in different column

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dynamic

I developed a loop which runs through and finds the line items corresponding to compatible products, the compatible product is on the active row in the loop in column y. I wanted to enter the name of the product in my array variable. How can I achieve this?

```
Sub findmultiplemodelid()
Dim item As Variant
ActiveCell.Select
Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
item = ActiveCell.Value
Sheets("Lights").Select
Rows(3).Select

Dim rangeToSearch As Range
Selection.Find(What:=item, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
     q = ActiveCell.row()
     z = ActiveCell.Column()
     Dim gmodels() As String
    Range(Cells(q + 1, z), Cells(72, z)).Select
     Set rangeToSearch = Selection
    Set foundRange = rangeToSearch.Find(What:="0", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues,                                                      LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) 'First Occurrence
Selection.Find(What:="0", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    m = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Selection, 0)
    ReDim gmodels(0 To m)
    z = 1
    Do Until z > m
    foundRange.Activate
    Set foundRange = rangeToSearch.FindNext(foundRange)
    b = ActiveCell.row
    gmodels(z) = Range(Cells(b, 25).Value)


z = z + 1
    Loop
    foundRange.Activate
  End Sub
```

I Get an error on the gmodels(z)=Range(Cells(b,25).Value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
gmodels(z)=Cells(b,25).Value
```